# Serial port - ESP8288 (TCP/IP) - WiFi - "Virtual serial port on my linux/windows PC" [Solved]

Tags: softwareserial

Is there an way to transport a serial port via TCP/IP to a PC.

The goal is to have a ESP8266 dongle that I connect to a router, switch or other device with a serial port for configuring.

I have found RFC 2217 that is suitable for the goal. Is there a arduino implementation ? Or any other way to get to the goal?

Comment: You mean besides the example that comes with the ESP8266 boards package that does just what you want?

Comment: Now I have to take a look at the examples.
A FB friend pointed me to https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link/ that looks like it will do the work as well. Thx

Comment: There's one called (I think) WiFiSerial. I took that and built on it to add RFC2217 support a while back. Never got round to testing it since I don't have an RFC2217 client, but I have used it for programming boards remotely.

Comment: Majenko, could you share the code?

Comment: If I can find it, sure.

Comment: Here you go - make of it what you will.  If you fancy pushing any changes and fixes back as a PR in Github that'd be great. https://github.com/MajenkoProjects/WiFiSerialDTR